# Prevent column from being copied to clipboard

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Is there a way to prevent a column from being copied to the clipboard?

I currently have row-grouping enabled with `groupDisplayType: 'groupRows'` and `enableRangeSelection: true`

If I drag a selection across rows, and thus across the row-group labels, they get included in the clipboard payload - I would like to exclude it, is this possible? I don't see any clipboard related events related to copying data, only pasting

I first tried setting `gridOptions.copyGroupHeadersToClipboard=false` but this did not prevent it from being copied / pasted

I also tried implementing `processCellForClipboard` and I can `return params.node.group ? undefined : params.value` however it still creates a blank row in the pasted data from the clipboard (an improvement but is there a way to remove the row completely?)

The most radical approach I tried was implementing `onRangeSelectionChanged` and basically de-selecting (by splitting the CellRange objects into two if a row-group cell existed in the middle of one) and calling `api.clearRangeSelection()` and `api.addCellRange()` but this was flaky at best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this by implementing the `sendToClipboard` event, here the `data` is a pipe-delimited string that you can process.

First I split it into rows by doing a `.split("\r\n")` then I get the indexes of all row-group rows by combination of iterating over the range of `api.getRangeCells()` and calling `api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex()` to check the `group` property and recording the `rowIndex`

I then take the lowest starting index of all the range select objects, and then `delete splitRows[groupRowIndex - startOffset]` then `.filter(Boolean).join("\r\n")` again

You then need to send the processed data to the clipboard via `navigator.clipboard.writeText()`